# Error build-impl.xml:1033: The module has not been deployed

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans-7, glassfish-3

I'm not able to deploy any of myprojects in Netbeans now.

I'm using Netbeans 7.3 Beta 2. My projects are with GlassFish server 3+ .

It is showing me the error

> "build-impl.xml:1033: The module has not been deployed."

Comment: Hey I am getting the same Error. Did you find any solution for this ?